# Intersection of two sets in most optimized way

Tags: c#, performance, set

Given two sets of values, I have to find whether there is any common element among them or not i.e. whether their intersection is null or not.

Which of the standard C# collection will suit best (in terms of performance) for this purpose? I know that `linq` has a `Intersect` extension method to find out the intersection of two list/arrays but my focus is on performance in terms of `Big-O notation`.

And what if I have to find out the intersection of two sets as well?

Comment: "Big O" is not a performance measure - it's a complexity measure.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Well, if you use LINQ's `Intersect` method it will build up a `HashSet` of the second sequence, and then check each element of the first sequence against it. So it's O(M+N)... and you can use `foo.Intersect(bar).Any()` to get an early-out.

Of course, if you store one (either) set in a `HashSet<T>` to start with, you can just iterate over the other one checking for containment on each step. You'd still need to build the set to start with though.

Fundamentally you've got an O(M+N) problem whatever you do - you're not going to get cheaper than that (there's *always* the possibility that you'll have to look at every element) and if your hash codes are reasonable, you should be able to achieve that complexity easily. Of course, some solutions may give better constant factors than others... but that's performance rather than complexity ;)

EDIT: As noted in the comments, there's also [`ISet<T>.Overlaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412095%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - if you've already got either set with a static type of `ISet<T>` or a concrete implementation, calling `Overlaps` makes it clearer what you're doing. If *both* of your sets are statically typed as `ISet<T>`, use `larger.Overlaps(smaller)` (where larger and smaller are in terms of the size of the set) as I'd expect an implementation of `Overlaps` to iterate over the *argument* and check each element against contents of the set you call it on.

Comment: if both `foo` and `bar` implement `ISet`, I think `foo.Overlaps(bar)` should be the best choice and work faster or equal in speed to `foo.Intersect(bar).Any()`

Comment: @YMC: I'd expect them both to be pretty much equal, to be honest. `Overlaps` might be very slightly faster, just because it can avoid creating the extra set internally. It's also more obvious, of course - I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: What if we have to take an intersection between more than 2 hashsets? For e.g. we have to take intersection of 6 hashsets i.e. hs1, hs2, hs3, hs4, hs5, hs6? And we dont know before hand that we have 6 hashsets or any number of them?

Comment: @FarazAhmad: Rather than explore this in comments, I'd suggest asking a new question with examples of what you want etc :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766387/best-way-to-take-an-intersection-of-more-than-two-hashsets-in-c-when-we-donot

Comment: @JonSkeet if the two sets are sets of strings, is it possible I could improve performance (as opposed to complexity), by chaining the strings together into a longer string, then using the string contains functions, rather than using enumerables and hashsets?

Comment: @StephenHolt: I doubt it. That sounds to me like it would probably be significantly slower.

Comment: "chaining the strings together into a longer string, then using the string contains functions" -- You can't get set intersection from that, and even if you could it would be a horrible idea.

Comment: It is too bad `Intersect` doesn't check for an existing `HashSet` and copy it rather than create a `Set` from it.

Comment: @NetMage: It wouldn't be able to tell whether the existing `HashSet` used the same equality comparison as the one that the Intersect call wants. (I thought I'd talked about that in EduLinq somewhere, but I can't find it now.)

Comment: `public IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer` ? I guess the problem (could be) that a comparer is an instance of a class, and not a singleton instance... but it would work when the default comparer is being used.

Comment: @NetMage: Interesting, I wasn't aware (or had forgotten) that you could get the comparer - but yes, that would lead to situations where the performance could change radically due to subtle code changes of equal-but-distinct comparers. I'm also not entirely sure that it would help, due to spotted repeated source values - you can't just stream `first` and check whether elements in `second` are present, because if the same value appears in `first` twice, it shouldn't be returned twice. So you need to create *some* extra collection.

Comment: I see - mine did `first.Distinct()` but I supposed cloning a `HashSet` is more efficient than using `Add`?

Comment: @NetMage: I'm afraid at this point I don't know what "mine did" means in this context, but I think we're really beyond what Stack Overflow comment threads were designed for.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned , Applying `Any()` will give you some performance.

I tested it on pretty big dataset and it gave 25% improvements.

Also applying `larger.Intersect(smaller)` rather than the opposite is very important, in my case, it gave 35% improvements.

Also ordering the list before applying intersect gave another 7-8%.

Another thing to keep in mind that depending on the use case you can completely avoid applying intersect.

For example, for an integer list, if the maximum and minimum are not within the same bounders you don't need to apply intersect since they will never do.

The same goes for a string list with the same idea applied to first letter.

Again depending on your case, try as much as possible to find a rule where intersection is impossible to avoid calling it.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing the performance testing. Saved me a bunch of time trying to figure out how to optimize my code.