# Using foreach and hashtable to find common element in three arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to find common element in three arrays. I am using Hashtable for this purpose as many people suggested here that it gives O(n) and its better.
Here is the code I have tried..

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class newAttempt
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Hashtable hm = new Hashtable();
            int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int[] b = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
            int[] c = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 };
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                hm.Add(i, a[i]);
            }

            foreach(int k in b)
                if (hm.Contains(k))
                {
                    foreach (int j in c)
                        if (hm.Contains(j))
                            Console.WriteLine(j);
                }


          Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting ouput as
3
4
3
4

I want my program to stop looking when it finds out that 4 is the only element which is common in this case. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 int[] b = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
 int[] c = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 };

 var result = a.Intersect(b).Intersect(c).ToArray(); // 4
```

Comment: What will be complexity for this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use `list.Intersect` function , this is example .

```
var list1 = new string[] {"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
var list2 = new string[] {"4", "5"};
var commonElement = list1.Intersect(list2);
foreach (string s in commonElement ) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
4
5
```

For more information ,

[This](http://www.dotnetperls.com/intersect) is the example of Intersection or array !

Comment: I dont want to use lists. An interger array is required.

Comment: @GauravK.: Lists? What lists? (Note, the answer uses **string arrays**, but that shouldn't stop you from applying it to int arrays.) If the result should be an array type just do: `list1.Intersect(list2).ToArray<int>();`

Comment: @Gaurav K , this is object type :) But I add a link in my answer , Check this link . I'm sure it may help you :)

Comment: @elgonzo yes.. got that.. thank you for poiting it out.

Comment: @zey yes that link helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking if the inner number is the same as the outer loop's number, so essentially you're printing *all* numbers in b and c that are in `hm`. Replace your inner loop by:

```
 foreach (int j in c)
   if (j==k) // hm.Contains(j) is covered by the previous hm.Contains(k)
     Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Edit: The other answer's intersect method is preferable for C#. Alternately, you can convert the arrays to a Set before performing this operation to improve performance for longer sequences.

Comment: Yes it worked. But I want this program to stop when it finds first element itself.. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Easy - Just have an `isfound` flag and check and break in your loop using or replace the last `Console.Writeline(j)` with a `{Console.WriteLine(j);return;}`

Comment: Can you also tell me what is the complexity of this program?

Comment: O(n^2) because of your 2 foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Extension Method *Intersect* from linq.

```
var hm1 = new HashSet<int>(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
var hm2 = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 });
var hm3 = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 });

var intersection = hm1.Intersect(hm2).Intersect(hm3);

foreach (var i in intersection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: @elgonzo in this trivial case it's senseless, because the Arrays have to be copied into the sets. But I think / hope, that Gauravs code was just an minimal example. If the problem scales up and he writes into the HashSets directly, he should get a better performance compared to the array solution.

Comment: @otis23, please forgive me my 'brain fart' (i deleted it shortly after i wrote it). But no worries, it was nothing a cup of good hot coffee couldn't fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to something like

```
foreach (int k in b)
    if (hm.Contains(k))
    {
        foreach (int j in c)
            if (j == k && hm.Contains(j)) //changes here
                Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
```

If you wish to exit the for loops once a match has been found you can try something like

```
bool found = false;
for (int bIndex = 0; !found && bIndex < b.Length; bIndex++)
{
    int k = b[bIndex];
    if (hm.Contains(k))
    {
        for (int cIndex = 0; !found && cIndex < c.Length; cIndex++)
        {
            int j = c[cIndex];
            if (j == k && hm.Contains(j))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j);
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using for loop is not good if complexity is considered right?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use the intersect as describe in the other posts. Performancewise, it also seems like a better option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527595/intersection-of-two-sets-in-most-optimized-way

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are checking the first array with second array.if match then the first array with third array.
but what we need is,if the first to array have a match hen we want to check if that value is present in third array.only that particular value.
but your checking the whole values of first array with the third array

```
 public  static void main(String args[])
        {
            Hashtable hm = new Hashtable();

            int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Integer[] b = new Integer[]{ 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
            int[] c = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 };
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++)
            {
                hm.put(i,a[i]);
            }
         for(int k:b)
         {
             if (hm.contains(k))
                {
                   for(int j:c)
                   {
                        if (k==j)  //here is the change
                        {
                            System.out.print(j);
                        }
                   }
                }
         }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq. Intersect method will be good for such purpose.
But, do you want to find out intersections just using loops and Hashtable?

this code should work:

```
        Hashtable hm = new Hashtable();
        int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] b = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
        int[] c = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 };            

        foreach (var iA in a)
        {
            foreach (var iB in b)
            {
                if (iA == iB && !hm.ContainsKey(iA))
                {
                    hm.Add(iA, iA);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var iC in c)
        {
            if (hm.ContainsKey(iC))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iC);
                hm.Remove(iC);
            }
        }
```