# time/space complexity for .net intersect() method

Tags: .net, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

This previous SO post describes using the .NET Intersect() method:

[Intersection of two sets in most optimized way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527595/intersection-of-two-sets-in-most-optimized-way)

It describes the big o complexity of the method as o(m+n).  Is that the big o complexity for both time *and* space?

Also, I read somewhere else that n should go before m in big o notation so the complexity above should be written as o(n+m).  Is n before m the proper sequence or does the sequence of these variables not matter (very much) with big o notation?

Answer (score 1):

(1) The answer describes building a hashset out of one list and checking the elements in the other list against it. The space complexity comes out of building the hashset. The size of the hashset is proportional to the number of elements that get put in it, either m or n, depending on which collection you build the hashset out of. Let's say you build the hash set out of the bigger set in the worst case. Then the space complexity is O(max(m, n)). This complexity class is identical to O(m + n). Why? Because max(m, n) < 1*(m + n) for all positive m, n; and m + n <= 2*max(m, n) for all positive m, n. So yes, the time and space complexity of the method described are both O(m + n) or, equivalently, O(max(m, n)).

(2) m + n <= 1*(n + m) for all positive m, n; and n + m <= 1*(m + n) for all positive m, n. Therefore, O(m + n) is identical to O(n + m).

Answer (score 0):

> Is that the big o complexity for both time and space?

If you are going by O(m + n) method, the space complexity will be O(`m < n ? m : n`). Why? You can keep the smaller one of those m and n sized set in memory and then read 1 item at a time from the bigger one to test whether that one item of the bigger one is in the smaller one. Otherwise if you will keep both of them out of memory, the space complexity will become O(1) while the time complexity will shoot to O(mn).

> Is n before m the proper sequence or does the sequence of these variables not matter (very much) with big o notation?

Since m + n = n + m, it doesn't matter at all. If the complexity would be something like O(m Log n) or O(mn<sup>2</sup>), then I'm sure you can't write it as O(n Log m) or O(nm<sup>2</sup>).