# Elegant way to query a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, open-closed-principle

I am trying to create an elegant and extensible way of querying a dictionary which maps an enum to a set of strings.

So I have this class `SearchFragments` that has the dictionary in it. I then want a method wherein consumers of this class can simply ask "HasAny" and, this is the bit where I am struggling, simply pass in some query like expression and get the boolean answer back.

```
public class SearchFragments
{
    private readonly IDictionary<SearchFragmentEnum, IEnumerable<string>> _fragments;

    public SearchFragments()
    {
        _fragments = new Dictionary<SearchFragmentEnum, IEnumerable<string>>();
    }

    public bool HasAny(IEnumerable<SearchFragmentEnum> of)
    {
        int has = 0;
        _fragments.ForEach(x => of.ForEach(y => has += x.Key == y ? 1 : 0));
        return has >= 1;
    }
}
```

The problem with the way this currently is, is that consumers of this class now have to construct an `IEnumerable<SearchFragmentEnum>` which can be quite messy.

What I am looking for is that the consuming code will be able to write something along the lines of:

```
searchFragments.HasAny(SearchFragmentEnum.Name, SearchFragmentEnum.PhoneNumber)
```

But where that argument list can vary in size (without me having to write method overloads in the `SearchFragments` class for every possible combination (such that if new values are added to the `SearchFragmentEnum` at a future date I won't have to update the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the params keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword)

Comment: try this:
`return of?.Any(_fragments.ContainsKey) ?? false;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`params[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

```
public bool HasAny(params SearchFragmentEnum[] of)
{ ...
```

Sidenote: you know that LIN(Q) queries should just query a source and never cause any side-effects?  But your query does unnecessarily increment the integer:

```
_fragments.ForEach(x => of.ForEach(y => has += x.Key == y ? 1 : 0));
```

Instead use this (which is also more efficient and more readable):

```
return _fragments.Keys.Intersect(of).Any();
```

---

An even more efficient alternative to this is [Sergey's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722775/elegant-way-to-query-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp/44722813#comment76428474_44722775) idea:

```
return of?.Any(_fragments.ContainsKey) == true;
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was not aware of that, makes sense I guess it's the same kind of logical principle as the single responsibility from SOLID. I mean what I'd writtten compiles, but you raise a valid point. I will apply what you've said here :-)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that intersect is analogous (at least conceptually) to SQL inner join? By this I mean it does a boolean intersection of both collections?

Comment: @ThomasCook: `Intersect` is a set method that builds the intersection of two sequences(by ignoring duplicates). But since it is deferred executed it doesn't need to build the whole intersection. The `Any` at the end will stop as soon as one was found. If you wanted to know how many intersect you could append `Count` instead of `Any`. But then all must be evaluated.

Comment: @ThomasCook: if you want to compare with sql methods, it's similar to the T-SQL method [`INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

Comment: I would recommend against using `_fragments.Keys` - that can be quite slow for ConcurrentDictionary due to locking. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs

Comment: Intersect is uneccessary. it is in O(N+M). This is a dictionary. You can just simply iterate the input array and check for containment.

Comment: @adjan: you haven't understood how `Intersect` and LINQ's deferred execution works

Comment: I would presume that `Intersect` works by generating a Hashset behind the scenes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527633/34092). I'd be surprised if that was faster than `public bool HasAny(params SearchFragmentEnum[] of) {
    return of.Any(_fragments.ContainsKey);
} ` since that just enumerates `of` once and then does a small number of (cheap) hash lookups. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @mjwills: you really care about 1ms more or less? That's micro optimization at it's "best". I have edited my answer to adapt Sergeys approach. It's really nice, but not because it might be more efficient but because it's still clear and readable.

Comment: Have a read of what the `Intersect` method does. https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs - in short it takes the second parameter and converts it to a set and then iterates over the first parameter and does hash lookups. This is an odd solution since your first parameter is **already** a `Dictionary` - it can already do hash lookups! @adjan 's earlier comment was correct. You are right that since it is deferred it doesn't need to build the whole intersection - but it does need to take the hit to (unnecessarily) build the set upfront.

Comment: @mjwills: it takes the second(which is the `params[]`, so probably one or two parameters not much more, otherwise the sequence overload would have been used). Then it enumerates the `KeyCollection`(not the dictionary as you've said) and looks if a key was in this little set. If so it is yielded. Due to the `Any` it will stop after the first found key.

Comment: Correct @TimSchelter - that is what it does. Apologies for not mentioning that explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

For variable sized arguments in c# you use the `params` keyword:
    public int HasAny(params SearchFragmentEnum[] of)

The .Net API usually offers a couple of overloads of this for performance reasons; the parameters passed are copied into a new array. Explicitely providing overloads for the most common cases avoids this.

```
public int HasAny(SearchfragmentEnum of1)
public int HasAny(SearchFragmentEnum of1, SearchFragmentEnum of2)
etc.
```

Instead of using params you could also consider marking your enum with the `[Flags]` attribute. Parameters could than be passed like `HasAny(SearchFragmentEnum.Name | SearchFragmentEnum.PhoneNumber`. Examples abundant on StackOverflow (e.g. [Using a bitmask in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp))

Answer (score 3):

Use the `params` keyword to allow a varying number of arguments. Further, you can simplify your code by looping over the smaller `of` array. Also, you are using a dictionary that has O(1) key check, so it is uneccessary to have an inner loop:

```
public bool HasAny(params SearchFragmentEnum[] of)
{
    foreach(var o in of) {
        if (this._fragments.ContainsKey(o))
            return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

or shorter with LINQ

```
public bool HasAny(params SearchFragmentEnum[] of) {
    return of?.Any(_fragments.ContainsKey) ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Great solution!